# No data in MySQL after using Docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker, hibernate, phpmyadmin

My task was to use docker to wrap my application from the database into containers. phpMyAdmin was used to monitor the database. Final stack: MySQL + Docker + phpMyAdmin + Java + Hibernate.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
 db:
  image: mysql:8.0.18
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: usersDB
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
 phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin:latest
   restart: always
   ports:
     - '8080:80'
   environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

After running the program and checking the operation of the database, it turns out that the data is written locally in MySQL Workbench, and not on phpMyAdmin. Absolutely empty.

[MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjVq1.png)

[phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngg2t.png)

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFGZP.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Aren't "MySQL Workbench" and "phpMyAdmin" both MySQL clients that don't themselves store data.  Do you somehow have two different databases set up, and your data is being written to the wrong one?  I assume that your code and this hibernate config file live in the `phpmyadmin` container.  Since the URL in the config mentions "localhost", it's not going to write to the database server running in the other container.  You would need to refer to the appropriate DNS name to get code in `phpmyadmin` to talk to the db in the other container.

Comment: If MySQL Workbench shows the data, and phpMyAdmin doesn't, then phpMyAdmin is connecting to a different database than MySQL Workbench and your application.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the hibernate project sits on your local computer. In the hibernate.cfg.xml file file above I see the database URL specified as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`. This will definitely save data to the local MySQL database. First, you need to change the host port in the line `3306:3306` of the docker-compose.yml file to to something like `3307:3306` if the local MySQL instance is already using port 3306. Next, change the database URL to point to the docker database instance `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/usersDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`